# Where to catch errors (err:ErrorType) that are thrown inside Delegate methods in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, error-handling, try-catch, core-bluetooth, swift2

I think I understood well do-try-throw-catch mechanism in Swift 2.0. All the thrown errors should be caught at somewhere in the code. Here is my question:

Suppose I have an application where UI is separated and communicates with a controller class. In the controller class, if I throw an error inside a delegate method (controller itself is delegate), where should I catch it?

Let me explain with an example.

Controller class uses CBCentralManagerDelegate from core bluetooth framework. Controller class is a delegate of CBCentralManager. There is also a ViewController which is a delegate of Controller class. What happens when I throw an error inside

```
public func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
```

Where can I catch the error? I guess I can't catch it because core bluetooth protocol methods are not implemented to throw errors since they are written in Objective C. I feel like my only option is using a controller protocol method which tells to UI that there is an error. Am I right?

What about the delegate methods that are not implemented in Objective-C? How can I catch the errors that are thrown from a delegate method that is written in Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't catch exceptions thrown from a delegate that is invoked by a framework like Core Bluetooth, not because the framework is written in Objective C.

Any exception that is thrown needs to be caught either within the delegate method itself (in case of a 'local' try->catch) or somewhere "up" the call stack, and the call stack in this case is from the Core Bluetooth framework->your delegate method.

It would be possible to define a delegate protocol such that a delegate method could throw an exception to indicate to the object calling the delegate that something went wrong but this is more typically done via a return value or handler block.  Even this wouldn't help you though because you are trying to throw an exception to an unrelated object in an asynchronous manner, so it doesn't really map to the exception pattern.

The traditional approach would be to use another delegate/protocol as you suggested or you could supply an error handling block/closure to your controller class.